# mcrypt module open function is missing in php7.2.7

Tags: php, openssl, php-7, mcrypt, php-openssl

In PHP5 I was able to use `mcrypt_module_open` and now in PHP7.2.7 (which I just upgrade to) the function is missing and while searching, I discovered that it has been replaced by `OpenSSL`.

My question is this: What is the equivalent of `mcrypt_module_open` in `OPenSSL`?

Comment: Do you need an equivalent for that function?

Comment: Yes I do. I greatly need it

Comment: Why? What do you think it does that OpenSSL would need to work the same way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP bindings to OpenSSL do not support incremental encryption as mcrypt did with `mcrypt_module_open`. The only encryption that's officially supported is one off encryption with `openssl_encrypt` and that's it.

If you want to do incremental encryption I would recommend doing https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat. That'll use OpenSSL to emulate incremental encryption, if it's available, and a pure-PHP implementation, otherwise.